# Do people who were vaccinated against chicken pox need to be vaccinated against shingles?

Tags: vaccination

Will people who never had chicken pox due to being vaccinated against it still need the shingles vaccine?

Comment: For [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we require prior research information when asking questions. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. This helps to provide an answer which will be more helpful. If you found nothing, what did you Google?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Varicella virus vaccine strain Oka (V-Oka) has in rare cases caused zoster in vaccinated people.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC535228/)

But this study on children show that even after vaccination the wild virus still ends up settling in your body: ["VZV was found in at least some ganglia of all of the other subjects."](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3540599/)

What is interesting about the singles vaccine is prior to October 2017 there was only one FDA approved vaccine which was just discontinued silently in November 2020 which leaves us with one vaccine again.

Comment: It's worth noting that "all of the other subjects" in this study is just 7 individuals, and folks who got the chickenpox vaccine as kids probably have not reached the older age at which shingles starts appearing in any large numbers yet. The bottom line is we don't know yet.